# Select only the rows where a condition is met (R)

Tags: r, filtering, subset

I am new to coding so any help is appreciated. I have a data frame (R studio) with 3 columns (20000 obs. and 3 variables). I would like to select only the rows where a condition is met: Keep row if Column "J" == Column "I" + 141.

I have tried the following without success:

```
out_df[out_df$j == out_df$i+"141", ]

out_df_filter_large <- subset(out_df_filter, "i+141" = "j" & !duplicated(cbind(pmin(i, j), pmax(i, j))))
```

Comment: What is the idea behind the double quotes around the value of 141. Are the variables `i` and `j` numeric? You can check with `is.numeric(out_df$i)`.

Comment: You are probably misunderstanding some very basic R synthax. In R, `"something"` is a character (AKA string) scalar. `"141"` is not a number, but `141` is. Modifying the code to `out_df[out_df$j == out_df$i+ 141, ]` may work, but this is just guessing.

Comment: Please go into the tour and check some important stack overflow guidelines before posting questions. This question is missing properly formatted code and a reproducible example 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Onyambu I share your frustration, but please don't welcome a new user's first question by yelling at them.

Comment: Welcome to the site leolima! It's pretty hard to help you with the information you've provided. Could you please (a) share a few rows of sample data. `dput()` is the friendliest way to share sample data, `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data including all the class information. Extra good if you make sure the subset of data you choose illustrates the problem well (i.e., has some rows that should be kept and some that should be dropped). Fake data is fine as long as it illustrates the problem...

Comment: (b) show the desired result for that sample input. (c) Generally, "without success" or "didn't work" isn't super helpful. Were there errors or warnings? What did they say? Or is the result just not what you expect?

Comment: @GregorThomas ohh shoot. I did not realize the phone was on Caps lock. My mistake. I totally own it